# Go: Unable to initialize struct

Tags: go

I am unable to initialize a struct, even though it does not show any linting error, it throws error while compiling

#### Error

```
$ go run main.go 
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:19:10: undefined: Application
```

Here's the struct:

```
/* app.go */

type Application struct {

    config struct {
        port string      // to be read from the command line flag 
        env string       // to be read from the command line flag 
        api string       // to be read from the command line flag 

        stripe struct {
            secret string  // to be read from the environment variable 
            key string     // to be read from the environment variable
        }

    } 

    infoLog   *log.Logger
    errorLog  *log.Logger 
    templateCache map[string]*template.Template
    version   string 

    DB *sql.DB
    Router *mux.Router

}
```

And here's how I am initializing it:

```
/* main.go */

app := Application{}
```

The code full code is [here](https://github.com/karankumarshreds/GoStripe/tree/master/cmd/web)

*Would really appreciate the help, thanks!*

Comment: Are these two files in the same package?

Comment: Do not use go run, use go build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `go run .` (here you're passing the folder instead of the files) or `go run main.go app.go routes.go`.

If you just run `go run main.go` it'll only load main.go which doesn't have any direct reference to the other files so it can't find the struct defined in the other files. By passing the folder containing all the main package files or passing all of the files explicitly then there's no confusion.

Comment: I ran into the problem myself. I've found if I need multiple files, it's easier to put additional files into non-main packages that way the main file can reference it. Better organized code and this problem goes away.